# Run an IBM OS/2 related command on remote server through Ansible playbook but hangs, no response

Tags: ansible, command

I have a playbook, as below:

```yaml
tasks:
- name: Execute a program_A on managed node
  win_command: 'D:test\program_A.exe'
```

I run this playbook but hung and no any response on managed node (*Windows 2012*). (i.e. there is a `program_A.exe` process generated on managed node but no response, it's CPU usage time is always 0%)

I also tired to replace `win_command` by `win_shell` module, `raw` module, but it still hung and no response on managed node...

When I try to open a command window on the managed node to run `D:\test\program_A.exe` directly, the `program_A.exe` was successfully executed.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the exe file is executed by the same privilege. eg. when you directly execute it, you are using Administrator, but in playbook, you may use guest rule.